# É possível mudar a cor do marcador Marker no Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

Estou usando o marcador da API do Google Maps (JS) sem problemas na minha aplicação. O código abaixo funciona perfeitamente:

```
var mapa = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa"), {
    center: {lat: latitude, lng: longitude}, zoom: 10
    });
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: endereco, size: new google.maps.Size(200, 200)
});
var marcador = new google.maps.Marker({ position: {lat: latitude, lng: longitude}, map: mapa}); 
google.maps.event.addListener(marcador, 'click', function() { 
    infowindow.open(mapa, marcador);
});
```

Eu gostaria de trocar a cor deste marcador, e talvez até fornecer opções para o usuário customizá-lo. Só para deixar claro, me refiro ao "balãozinho" vermelho que colocamos nos endereços: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A API permite a troca de cor do marcador? Como? Procurei aqui na comunidade e só encontrei perguntas sobre a customização do marcador trocando-o por alguma imagem, mas o que eu quero é mais simples, apenas trocar a cor mesmo. Obrigado.

Comment: A cor, acho que não. Mas você pode definir uma imagem para ser o marcador.

Comment: @renan substituir por imagem eu vi. Há algumas perguntas sobre isso aqui. Mas não quero fazer a gambiarra de criar uma imagem de um marcador com outra cor. Acredito que tenha um jeito, eu já vi aplicações com o marcador azul, por exemplo. Só não estou encontrando agora...

Comment: Se é referente ao mapa no browser...pode trocar o ícone para qualquer outro...qdo chegar em casa lhe mando o script

Comment: Deve ser [isto aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2473109/4056678) então.

Answer (score 2):

**Associar dados a um marcador**

É possível armazenar um objeto de dados arbitrários com um marcador usando `Marker.setTag()` e recuperar o objeto de dados usando `Marker.getTag()`, conforme mostrado neste código de exemplo.

```
/**
 * A demo class that stores and retrieves data objects with each marker.
 */
public class MarkerDemoActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        OnMarkerClickListener,
        OnMapReadyCallback {

    private static final LatLng PERTH = new LatLng(-31.952854, 115.857342);
    private static final LatLng SYDNEY = new LatLng(-33.87365, 151.20689);
    private static final LatLng BRISBANE = new LatLng(-27.47093, 153.0235);

    private Marker mPerth;
    private Marker mSydney;
    private Marker mBrisbane;

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.marker_demo);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    /** Chamado quando o mapa está pronto. */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        mMap = map;

        // Add some markers to the map, and add a data object to each marker.
        mPerth = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(PERTH)
                .title("Perth");
        mPerth.setTag(0);

        mSydney = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(SYDNEY)
                .title("Sydney");
        mSydney.setTag(0);

        mBrisbane = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(BRISBANE)
                .title("Brisbane");
        mBrisbane.setTag(0);

        // Set a listener for marker click.
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
    }

    /** Chamado quando o usuário clica em um marcador. */
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

        // Retrieve the data from the marker.
        Integer clickCount = (Integer) marker.getTag();

        // Check if a click count was set, then display the click count.
        if (clickCount != null) {
            clickCount = clickCount + 1;
            marker.setTag(clickCount);
            Toast.makeText(this,
                           marker.getTitle() +
                           " has been clicked " + clickCount + " times.",
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        // Return false to indicate that we have not consumed the event and that we wish
        // for the default behavior to occur (which is for the camera to move such that the
        // marker is centered and for the marker's info window to open, if it has one).
        return false;
    }
}
```

Eis alguns exemplos de cenários quando é útil armazenar e recuperar dados com marcadores:

O seu aplicativo pode oferecer vários tipos de marcadores e você quer tratá-los de forma diferente quando o usuário clica neles. Para fazer isto, é possível armazenar uma String com o marcador indicando o tipo.
Você pode estar fazendo interface com um sistema que tem identificadores de registro únicos, onde os marcadores representam registros específicos neste sistema.
Os dados do marcador podem indicar uma prioridade a ser usada ao decidir o índice Z de um marcador.

**Personalizar a cor do marcador**

É possível personalizar a cor da imagem padrão do marcador passando um objeto BitmapDescriptor para o método icon(). Você pode usar um conjunto de cores predefinidas no objeto BitmapDescriptorFactory ou definir uma cor de marcador personalizada com o método BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(float hue). A tonalidade é um valor entre 0 e 360, representando pontos em uma paleta de cores.

```
static final LatLng MELBOURNE = new LatLng(-37.813, 144.962);
Marker melbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                          .position(MELBOURNE)
                          .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
```

SEGUE OUTROS DADOS NESTE LINK: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker?hl=pt-br